# minimum no of states required for A(BC)*D?

Tags: dfa

What are the minimum no. of states required in dfa of the language: A(BC)*D? Is it 3 or 4?
By 3 I mean, can I write "BC" on single arrow?
If possible please explain using a diagram.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Typically, edges are labeled purely with single characters.

Comment: yeah, but is it against the rules to use 2 symbols on a same "arrow"?

Comment: Yep. "Edge" is the more proper term for "arrow." :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transition function of a DFA is typically defined as mapping a DFA state and one input symbol to another DFA state, take [Wikipedia's formal definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Deterministic_finite_automaton&oldid=599107409#Formal_definition) as an example:

> A deterministic finite automaton M is a 5-tuple, (Q, Σ, δ, q<sub>0</sub>, F),
>   consisting of
>
> - a finite set of states (Q)
> - a finite set of input symbols called the alphabet (Σ)
> - a transition function (δ : Q × Σ → Q)
> - a start state (q<sub>0</sub> ∈ Q)
> - a set of accept states (F ⊆ Q)

So with the usual definition of a DFA, you cannot have transitions over a sequence of two elements of the alphabet. A common kind of automaton that allows more complex transitions are [Generalized nondeterministic finite automata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_nondeterministic_finite_automaton).